# Never complete beyond ambiguous choices

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, zsh-completion

I'm trying to figure out how to customize zsh completion so that it **never** completes beyond an ambiguous result by just hitting tab. Here's an example.

```
$ emacs f<TAB>
  food fool
(completes into)
$ emacs foo
  food fool
```

Importantly, if I press TAB after 'emacs foo' I would like zsh to beep instead of complete into the menu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descending into the completion menu is controlled via the `AUTO_MENU` option. This is a default option which can be turned off by setting in your `.zshrc` the 'no' prefixed option.

```
setopt noautomenu
```

[ZSH Documentation: 16 Options](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html)